# How can I make recursive function for binary tree in matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, binary-search-tree

V is a image matrix.D0 and D1 are right and left root of binary trees for level 1. 
this is a binary tree and it has 8 level. this means  a lots of code . I want to make it with recursive function.And as an Output I need all roots of means in array M. Please any idea to make it recursive?

```
clear all;clc;
V=imread('tire.tif');
[x y]=size(V);
U=V*0;

  M=zeros(1,511);


  % LEVEL 1
  M(1,1)=mean(V(:));

  % LEVEL 2
  D0=V(V<=mean(V(:))); % right root for V
  M(1,2)=mean(D0(:));
  D1=V(V>mean(V(:)));  %left root for V
  M(1,3)=mean(D1(:));

  % LEVEL 3
  D00=D0(D0<=mean(D0(:)));  %left root for D0
  M(1,4)=mean(D00(:));
  D01=D0(D0>mean(D0(:)));  %left root for D0
  M(1,5)=mean(D01(:));

  D10=D1(D1<=mean(D1(:)));   %right root for D1
  M(1,6)=mean(D10(:));
  D11=D1(D1>mean(D1(:)));    %left root for D1
  M(1,7)=mean(D11(:));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for. The tricky part is keeping track of the indices (as usual).

```
function M = myrecfun(V, M, n_max, n, i)
%n: current level (of recursions)
%i: an integer in [1, 2^(n-1)]
i_start = 2^n;
meanV = mean(V(:));
if n == 1
M(1) = meanV
end 
DR = V(V <= meanV);
DL = V(V > meanV);
iR = i_start + 2*i - 2;
iL = i_start + 2*i - 1;
M(iR) = mean(DR);
M(iL) = mean(DL);
if n < n_max
M = myrecfun(DR, M, n_max, n+1, iR - i_start + 1);
M = myrecfun(DL, M, n_max, n+1, iL - i_start + 1);
else % else of if n < n_max
M;
end % end of  if n < n_max
end % of myrecfun
```

Call the code:

```
n_max = 8;
V = 100*rand(100,100); %Just my example
M = zeros(1, 2^(n_max+1)-1);
Mout = myrecfun(V, M, n_max, 1, 1);
```

Test the output:

> > sum(Mout< 50)

ans =

256

> > sum(Mout > 50)

ans =

255

Comment: realy thanks for interesting my question. it give an error for iL   ??? Undefined function or variable 'iL'.

Error in ==> myrecfun at 15
M(iL) = mean(DL);

Error in ==> denemerecrsve at 4
Mout = myrecfun(V, M, n_max, 1, 1); 
>>     @bbarker

Comment: i write iL = i_start + 2*i -1;  and the code worked well thanks for help

Comment: I thought it was there but there was an indentation issue: fixed now.

Comment: Do you have `smqt` source in MATLAB? if yes can you give it to me?